# Laravel routes not working correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have extracted the laravel.phar contents into *c:\www\laravel* correctly.

I have two problems which I believe are related.

- I have to visit *localhost/laravel/public/* instead of just *localhost/laravel/* to get the default *"you have arrived."*
- If I setup a test in *app/routes.php* labelled **1)** below and visit *localhost/laravel/public/testdir* or *localhost/laravel/testdir* I get a *404 not found* error from *nginx*

**1)**

```
    Route::get('/testdir', function()
    {
        return 'Working';
    });
```

The Routes seem to be partially working because if I setup are route like **2)** below and visit *localhost/laravel/public/* I will see "Base test" correctly.

**2)**

```
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return 'Base test';
    });
```

My enviroment specifics

- c:\www\laravel Project Directory.
- Laravel 4.1
- Nginx nginx-1.5.12
- php-5.4.27-nts-Win32-VC9-x86

Nginx.Conf file setup

```
http {

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   C:/www;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           C:/www;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you set the documentroot path to `laravel/public`? you get the same errors when you'd use the builtin server with `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: and please post your nginx config

Comment: @zwacky I tried php artisan serve and this seems to fix the problems, visiting *localhost:8000* directs to *laravel/public* and *localhost/testdir* also redirects accordingly.

Comment: You just need to add/public to your domain route. As detailed by @user3348022

Comment: @keithm Have you read the comments under user3348022 answer? It still leaves parts broken unless I assign complete server blocks + cgi settings to cater for each and every Laravel project. There is a workaround I am sure but I do not know it and I have spent 4 hours messing around with all sorts of paths inside Laravel and nginx.conf settings. Its a absolute joke that something so common and fundamental to using Laravel isn't documented by them in the official docs. I will be using the php artisan serve for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your nginx config to match the public folder of your laravel installation.

Here's a sample to get you started:

```
http {

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   C:/www/;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /laravel/ {
        root   C:/www/laravel/public/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           C:/www/;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Make sure to restart nginx after you have made changes to the config!

Update:

Since we now defined `C:/www` on the server level, everything will be served according to the config made at server level. `location /laravel/ overrides this with its own block. All scripts not located under /laravel/ will work as before...

Comment: After trying this neither now work, I get nginx 404 not found for both *localhost/laravel/* and also *localhost/laravel/public/*

Comment: Have you tried http:://localhost/ ? I also added another line to the location / block...

Comment: Just noticed your edit, I appended the *try_files* variable, this now changes the previuos error message, my page now displays *No input file specified. * for both *localhost/laravel/public* and *localhost/laravel/*

Comment: Ok, If I set my location ~ \.php$ path root likewise, it seems to work
However before I mark it I have to test some other non-laravel projects, not sure if this is going to make everything else broken as the settings are just for that *laravel* directory

Comment: Well if you want to server other directories else than this particular one, you would have to copy the `location /` block and alter it to match your other folders, of course.. e.g. `location /laravel` and `location /`and `location /myproject`

Comment: Yes I tried that, it doesnt work, Also it doesnt seem correct that if I have to make a new location each time I put a directory in the base. For example, If I put in the conf 
*location / root C:\www*, then any folder inside C:\www would be accessable corresponding to its name in the url, like *c:\www\SO* = *localhost\SO*, This is how it worked before and having to make a new location block for every folder I make doesnt seem correct. Furthermore because I setup the *location ~ \.php$* root block likewise, this location now hogs all PHP scripts, I cannot make new location blocks*cont

Comment: *cont for this section too, my conf file will just become huge.

Comment: Oh, no no, you got me wrong here.. I'll update my answer accordingly!

Comment: I thought this would work but it doesn't. It now just reverts back to the "No input file specified. " which usually relates to the fastcgi block. Also even if this did work doesn't this mean for every laravel dir I make I have to insert 8 or so repetitive lines in the nginx.conf? Theoretically I thought all we would have to do is perhaps insert one line along the lines of *redirect lp/public/ lp/*. I thought Laravel was meant to be easy and simple to setup, the documentation says nothing about any of this and just leaves people in the dark. Not impressed whatsoever. Thanks for your help.